# MySQL to Solr import issue

Tags: solr

I have successfully imported data to solr.
when i say full import it shows appropriate no of rows fetched.
but when i search any thing related to data from fetched rows in solr admin it does not finds any result.
can any one help me out i want to search the data from database using solr admin

Comment: Try `q=*:*` to fetch everything that Solr indexed. What does this mean: "search the data from database using solr admin"

Comment: I want to see whether row fetched from mysql database are indexed or not

Comment: I have make changes in schema.xml,solrconfig.xml and created a file my-data-config.xml and in that i wrote query for fetching data from database But it shows result same as mysql query.Then there is no use of Solr. Actually I want to show data based on single name/field without the query which is same as mqsql database.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have commit=false? see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Commands

Answer (score 0):

In your query enter `*:*` which should return what your row data looks like.  You might have failed to set the  parameter in your schema.xml file.

Comment: I have added Field names and UniqueKey in Schema.xml file.Where should I enter *:*

Comment: when i do full import it shows the relevant rows fetched as its results. after thet when i to search some thing from admin page which is part of full import data the solr does not searches it.

Comment: You need to enter *:* in the admin panel where it says "Query String:" .  Unless you do this and tell us your output we really can't help you further.